# Android Getting Current date+ specfied integer time?

Tags: android

Currently, I have a time represented by a four character string (Example 2328). Is it possible to get android current date only + the time represented in string?

So that it will be represented in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it by using the set function

```
            String time = message.substring(7, 11);
             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
             c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(message.substring(7, 9)));
             c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(message.substring(9, 11)));

                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
                String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

here comes sample functions to format the date as you like, hope this helps

```
public static String getFormattedDate() {
        return getFormattedDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    public static String getFormattedDate(long millis) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(millis+"") || millis<=0) return "";

        return getFormattedDate(new Date(millis));
    }
    public static String getFormattedDate(Date date) {

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
            return sdf.format(date);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return "";
        }
    }
```